# How to unlock SQL Server database that is read only?

Tags: sql-server

I have locked the database with this query:

```
ALTER DATABASE drc2 SET READ_ONLY WITH NO_WAIT
```

Now, I want to get write access to this database again.  How can I unlock the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
USE [drc2 ]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [drc2] SET READ_WRITE WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```

If you face an error on above query that if the database is already in use, you can resolve the same by making database in single user mode

```
ALTER DATABASE [drc2] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

The above query will rollback any transaction which is running on that database and brings SQL Server database in a single user mode.